# Generic interface or generic subclass

Tags: java, inheritance, interface

I am developing a linear algebra library that fits my needs. Currently I have 2 ideas but I would like to know what are pros and cons of both of these structures to make the good choice.

For example with vectors :

```
//First structure (simple inheritance using generics 
//to prevent instanceof and casting in subclasses
public abstract class AbstractVector<T>{
    public abstract T method(T t){...}
    ...
}

public class Vector2 extends AbstractVector<Vector2>{
    public Vector2(){...}
    //Implements AbstractVector method, generic T is Vector2
    public Vector2 method(Vector2 vector){...}
}

public class Vector3 extends AbstractVector<Vector3>{...}

public class Vector4 extends AbstractVector<Vector4>{...}



//Second structure (using the structure of java AbstractList/List/ArrayList
//prevents instanceof and casting in subclasses )
public interface Vector<T>{
    T method(T t){...}
}

public abstract class AbstractVector<T> implements Vector<T>{...}

public class Vector2 extends AbstractVector<Vector2>{
    public Vector2(){...}
    //Implements Vector interface method, generic T is Vector2
    public Vector2 method(Vector2 vector){...}
}

public class Vector3 extends AbstractVector<Vector3>{...}

public class Vector4 extends AbstractVector<Vector4>{...}
```

In terms of usage :

```
//1st structure 
Vector2 vector2 = new Vector2();
Vector3 vector3 = new Vector3();
vector2.method(vector3) //Compile time error!

//2nd structure (I use Vector type main advantage of interface)
Vector vector2 = new Vector2();
Vector vector3 = new Vector3();
vector2.method(vector3) //Runtime error!
```

For now I have following pros and cons :

1. For first structure :
   Pros : Simple inheritance and compile time error
2. For second structure :
   Pros : This structure insert the generic type `Vector`
   Cons : Only runtime error

Am I missing pros/cons which would make one structure outweigh another ?

EDIT : The main purpose of this library is to use it for geometry definition and openGL rendering.

Comment: What should the Vector2, Vector3, Vector4 be? Are you trying to handle a dimension?

Comment: Yes, exactly, I handle dimension. When i add a dimension, I also add specific methods due to new dimension.

Comment: Cons for both: you've got to have a separate class for each dimension of Vector. How much of a con that is depends upon whether you are only applying this to particular problems, e.g. 3d graphics, where you primarily deal with 3- or 4-dimensional vectors.

Comment: This is the main idea, I want to use this library for 2 goals : 3D graphics and generic geometry (mainly transformations )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for having a `Set` interface, and separate implementation classes `HashSet`, `TreeSet` is genious. *It makes all code as general as possible, and keeps inheritance simple. It allows to extend the API in future, with backward compatibility (for other classes).*

And also there is the problem of one `Set` having a special feature: the `SortedSet` interface extending `Set` and only being implemented by `TreeSet`.

```
interface Vector {
}

class SparseVector implements Vector {
}

class UnitVector implements Vector {
}
```

---

```
interface IonicalVector extends Vector {
    IonicalVector rotate(double phi);
}

class QuatrionsVector implements IonicalVector {
    @Override
    public IonicalVector rotate(double phi) { ... }
}
```

---

Disadvantage is the overhead as in `LinkedList` of a `get(int index)` which does not fit it.

Personally I would go ahead with simple classes, and when different implementation are thinkable look what makes sense.

Mind you can also use the [**builder pattern**](https://jlordiales.me/2012/12/13/the-builder-pattern-in-practice/) to implement one interface by dynamically choosing a (private) implementation. A bit remotely like `Arrays.asList`.

```
Vector v = Vector.with().dim(4).quatrionic(true).build();
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, do you think i should divide it into two part : first with only theory (Vector class with dimension field) and a second one  with more specific class used by 3d graphics ?

Comment: Yes, a nice modular view helps to transfer a better insight to the user. Start with test-driven-development, using unit tests composing meaningful code samples.

Comment: Ok I have to learn Junit then! Thank you. Is a generic vector class and more specific vector class(2D/3D/4D for simplicity and performance, "sisters" of generic vector class) which inherit from the same abstract vector class acceptable for an API ?

Comment: In java 10 (9?) String will internally choose between `char[]`, 2byte UTF-16 arrays, or arrays with single byte encodings - as optimization. So you would be on the edge of the great development wave. But I would still start covering the large area before those choices. Just start developing and do not release too early, to be able to refactor things.

Answer (score 1):

I understand your intention. You want to make the dimension of a vector a compile-time constant and let the compiler check in operations (like addition, scalar multiplication) if the dimensions fit. I thought about these kind of things for some time in the past, but I couldn't figure out a good solution. Types can be parametrised by other types, but not by numbers.

My suggestion is to get rid of all the numbers in type definitions. Just define a class `Vector` with field `dimension`. Then you can check the compatibility of dimensions for every operations and get just one class (instead of n different ones). This is a huge benefit for testing and maintaining the code. The downside is that dimension problems cause runtime exceptions instead of compile problems. But having clear and uncluttered code is more important than that.

Comment: Thank you. I agree with your suggestion but it needs to insert dimension tests for each simple operation. Is it difficult to maintain this kind of code ?